# Crashlytics is sending stability alert but there arent any crashes

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I am getting stability alerts that my app is now going under 67% crash free users so of course I got scared: 
[image]
I went to Fabric to check what was happening and I see absolutely no crashes:

[image]
I also checked Firebase since I migrated the project, and nothing shows up there either.

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up,

The developer wrote in to support at fabric(at)support(dot)io and was able to have this issue resolved. The cause was an API key error, which caused reports to not be sent to the developers Fabric Dashboard.